# Linking my Node.js server to a third party website(peoplesoft) log in credentials to be able to post forms to their website.

Tags: node.js, https, jsonparser

Just trying to find out if this is possible. Basically I have a node.js server up and running with a excel to json parser set up. Now we would like to post the data to the website(peoplesoft). To do this we must first link the log in with the website right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a SOAP URL and consume it in Poeplesoft by creating a new node. All login credentials should be setup in PeopleSoft side. You need a Peoplesoft developer to help you with the setup.